# Do people actually do OO in C?

Tags: c, oop, virtual-functions

Member functions can be emulated in C by passing the `this` pointer explicitly. Virtual functions can be emulated by explicitly storing in every object a pointer to a global array of function pointers. Fine.

Now my question is, do people actually do this? I am wondering if it's worth teaching this technique, because I do not want to teach something to C freshmen that is practically never used in the real world.

(I need to fill the last day of a two-week introductory C course for people already familiar with OOP.)

Are there any relevant projects, libraries or frameworks that emulate OO in C in the manner described?

Comment: Even if it *is* used (and afaik, it is), is it something freshmen need to learn in a C course?

Comment: @jalf it's not that hard to understand. If somebody really well understands the basics of C, after some time he eventually will stumble upon this. And he will understand it.

Comment: I have found the good article http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf

Comment: I agree with jalf, I don't think it's something that should be brought up early, I personally don't think it's necessary at all. Imo, if you want to program OO, then use a OO-language. But to answer your question about libraries: Check out GLib and GObject.

Comment: @H2CO3 sure, it's not hard to understand. But as you say, once you know C you'll figure this out all on your own if you need it. So I'm questioning whether it's worth teaching in a freshman C class

Comment: @jalf See my edit; some alternatives for filling the last day that came to mind were `alloca`, practical uses for unions, the `struct` hack, `goto` for error handling, and variadic functions.

Comment: @FredOverflow After two weeks they are definitly not masters of C, so why not just do a summary to wrap things up and let them hear the important stuff one more time? That's how I would have wanted it if I was taking the course.

Comment: @Jite Sounds like a nice alternative plan. I guess you could say that I suffer from feature teacheritis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be used in practice, but it is incredibly valuable to learn the concept of the equivalence between member functions and functions that take the object as the first parameter. Having this concept in the back of their head will help them in many problems they will encounter down the road.

Day in and day out I see people asking questions on Stack Overflow about why it doesn't work to point to pass a member function to something requiring function pointer, and things like that. They think that member functions are just some magical functions that are part of an object, and over-complicate the whole situation. If they had realized that member functions were equivalent to functions that took the object as the first parameter, then the problem they're having (that to call the method they would somehow need both the member function pointer as well as the object), as well as possible solutions (somehow pass the object in separately, or make some kind of closure that captures the object) becomes apparent. Apparently, too many people just pretend that OO is "magic" and don't understand this.

In functional programming, we often teach people how data structures and local variables and all that stuff could be written purely in terms of manipulation of functions. Not that this is practical -- it would probably be inefficient -- but this impresses upon them something about the power of functions. And it helps them to understand things in a different way. And maybe down the road if they write a compiler or something, these equivalences will come in handy.

Computer science is all about equivalences and reductions, and how to think about one problem in terms of another. We reduce SAT-3 to subset sum, not because that's actually how we would actually solve the SAT-3 problem, but because this teaches us that subset sum is NP-complete.

Every once in a while, I come across a piece of code written by someone else, where non-instance methods take a pointer to a structure as an argument, and I see a pattern and a light bulb goes off in my head, and I say, ah-ha, this can be re-factored into an instance method, because I know about this equivalence. So you see, knowing these equivalences also helps us to write better, simpler code.

Answer (score 8):

I've about twenty years experience in C.  It was the first compiled language I learned and I've never needed to move on, so it's been C and only C, all the way.  I write code constantly at work and at home.  I have published a library of lock-free data structures.  I think I'm a competent C programmer.

With regard to your question, OO consists of a number of concepts.  One, for example, is instantiation, e.g a library with a new() and delete() and instances of a given entity (stack, list, etc).  C supports this and it is, of course, a very functional and useful approach.  I've used this approach for about fifteen years.

Many years ago I began experimenting with another OO concept, well supported in C++, inheritance.  I wanted an entity which contained other entities.  The problem then is exposing the API of the contained entites.  You can do it, but the fact is, the C language does not naturally express such an concept and approach.  It is not something I now use.

My advice is; a knife is a knife, a fork is a fork.  You can use either as the other, but it doesn't work well.  C does not naturally support some (important) OO concepts, such as inheritance.  Don't try to make C do these things.  If you want to do this, use C++.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do.

> Are there any relevant projects, libraries or frameworks that emulate OO in C in the manner described?

I wouldn't call it "emulating" just because there's no first-class language support. See [GObject](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/).

Answer (score 2):

A lot of project uses the Object oriented paradigms in C codebase. For various reasons they don't use CPP directly. For system level or performance intensive projects, Other languages don't cut the deal. So its a battle between cpp and c.

Why people emulate OO in C instead of full blown CPP is topic of heated arguments. Linus torvalds once famously stated, CPP compilers are not trustworthy. He has little faith on CPP generated code.

Linux kernel is a good example of implementing OO design patterns in C. You can read about how Linux kernel did it in this lwn.net article series :

[part1](http://lwn.net/Articles/444910/)

[part2](http://lwn.net/Articles/446317/)

There is a extensive free document lying around in internet which covers a full range implementation OO design patterns in C.

[ooc.pdf](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf)

You can find many other projects along the same road.

Examples:

[pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/)

[sofia](http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out TI's "DSP Algorithm Standard" / xDAIS framework.

There's a generic C API that every conforming DSP algorithm implementation implements (sorry for the tautology). The need for all this "art" stems from several issues common in the DSP world:

- relatively small RAMs
- multiple data channels (often parallel/concurrent)
- complex algorithm usage patterns
- something else I forget

The standard and framework aim at making it easier for DSP engineers to use 3rd party DSP algorithms.

There's an interface to configure an algorithm instance and query its memory requirements (based on the configuration) and there are support functions that actually manage the memory.

Some memory areas, scratchpads, can be allocated temporarily and given to an algorithm instance when it's active and taken away from it when it's inactive and given to another instance, effectively shared.

There's also functionality (and APIs) to move instance memory buffers to defragment memory.

There's more, but I'd need to reread the docs to recall the details.

See `IALG_*()` and `ALG_*()` interface methods for example.

Also, there are tools to validate implementations of the generic APIs. 3rd parties can request official validation of them from TI.

Some relevant links: [spru352g.pdf](http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/spru352g), [spru360e.pdf](http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/spru360e).